# wordpress, how do you change the information in the footer?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am building a website in wordpress, with the twentythirteen theme. And I want to get rid of the words "this is a blog... (the search bar)... recent posts... recent comments and so forth." But the only page that has any coding for the footer is the footer.php. Here is the coding for the footer.php. Is there anything I am like missing here? Because I am not seeing anything that I can change without the whole footer being removed in general. I am really stuck, can someone out there who can give me some clarity?

```
 <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the
 * #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?>

                </div><!-- #main -->
                <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
                        <?php get_sidebar( 'main' ); ?>

                        <div class="site-info">
                                <?php do_action( 'twentythirteen_credits' ); ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/',     'twentythirteen' ) );       ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentythirteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .site-info -->
                </footer><!-- #colophon -->
        </div><!-- #page -->

        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

there are two parts/components in your footer.

1. A module displayed
2. credits to WordPress.

if you want to remove side bar remove the code

```
 <?php get_sidebar( 'main' ); ?>
```

if you want to remove the credits then remove the following code:

```
<?php do_action( 'twentythirteen_credits' ); ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/',     'twentythirteen' ) );       ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentythirteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

else, remove both of them and you will get a clear footer.

Comment: If I remove the side bar it clears the whole footer, the second part doesn't do anything if you remove it. Thank-you for your help!

Comment: Second part removes the credit to WordPress etc. Yeah, if u can mention the site url it will be great

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to get rid of are the default widgets. If that's the case, go to Appearance > Widgets, and drag and drop everything you want to remove off of the 'Main Widget Area' drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

"this is a blog... (the search bar)... recent posts... recent comments  This is comes from widget. If you don't want this you need to remove those widget.